# launch a python console and control its output

Tags: python, subprocess

I need to launch a python console and control its output. I am using python subprocess.Popen() to a create a new instance.

I saved following code in a python script and running it from windows command prompt.  When I run the script it launches the python instance in current windows command prompt, do not launch it in a separate console.

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["C:\Python31\python.exe"], shell=False,
          #       stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                 stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out, _ = p.communicate()
print(out.decode())
```

Comment: Just FYI something to watch out for down the road is that stdout is buffered. So if you're not getting your output when expected you can try manually flushing or using stderr.

Answer (score 2):

In Windows you can spawn subprocesses in new console sessions by using the [CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE) creation flag:

```
from subprocess import Popen, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, PIPE

p = Popen(["C:\Python31\python.exe"], creationflags=CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)
```

Comment: newly opened console open and get vanish

Comment: As I need to control the output I have to use stdout=subprocess.PIPE

Comment: I also observe that if I use argument with the command then again newly opened console open and get vanish      p = Popen(["C:\Python31\python.exe  C:\demo.py"], creationflags=CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)

Answer (score 1):

If you are on windows you can use win32console module to open a second console for your thread or subprocess output. This is the most simple and easiest way that works if you are on windows.

Here is a sample code:

```
import win32console
import multiprocessing

def subprocess(queue):
    win32console.FreeConsole() #Frees subprocess from using main console
    win32console.AllocConsole() #Creates new console and all input and output of subprocess goes to this new console
    while True:
        print(queue.get())
        #prints any output produced by main script passed to subprocess using queue

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    multiprocessing.Process(target=subprocess, args=[queue]).start()
    while True:
        print("Hello World in main console")
        queue.put("Hello work in sub process console")
        #sends above string to subprocess and it prints it into its console

        #and whatever else you want to do in ur main process
```

You can also do this with threading. You have to use queue module if you want the queue functionality as threading module doesn't have queue

Here is the [win32console module documentation](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32console.html)